# SQL VBA - Update Fields in Table Based on Minimum Result from Calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

After a couple weeks of trying to figure this out, I have to phone a friend. I think I am getting further away the more I mess with it. I have two tables in MS Access (See Below)

The goal is to end up with a new field called ("O_CityRegion") in the table ("tblnewbid") that contains the Region of the closest city. So I need to use the latitude and longitude of each city, where the States' Regions match (simply to cut down on calculation time), and calculate the distance between them. Of the list of cities within the Region, I need to find the lowest distance and return the corresponding SubRegion into the field "O_CityRegion".

Mathematically speaking, I know the following formula works for calculating distance between coordinates:

```
(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-(Latitude1))) * COS(RADIANS(90-(Latitude2))) + SIN(RADIANS(90-(Latitude1))) * SIN(RADIANS(90-(Latitude2))) * COS(RADIANS((Longitude1)-(Longitude2))))*3958
```

It is just a matter of getting all the other parts working. I think I have been closer previously, but I just copied my code as it stands now.

Access Tables and fields within them:

```
tblnewbid

Origin // O_State Region // Latitude // Longitude

tblClosestCities

CityState // Latitude // Longitude // Region // SubRegion
```

Below is my code as it stands:

```
Private Sub btnInsertClosestCityRegion_Click()
Dim strSQL As Variant
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim Distance As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute ALTER TABLE [tblnewbid] ADD COLUMN O_CityRegion CHAR, dbFailOnError

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(Select [Origin] FROM [tblnewbid];)

rs1.MoveFirst

    strSQL = "UPDATE [tblnewbid] INNER JOIN [tblClosestCities]"
    strSQL = strSQL & ON [tblClosestCities].[Region] = tblnewbid.[O_StateRegion]
    strSQL = strSQL & SET [tblClosestCities].[SubRegion] = [tblnewbid].[O_CityRegion]
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM ( "
    strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT [tblClosestCities].[SubRegion], (3958 * ACOS( COS(RADIANS(90-[tblnewbid].[Latitude])) * COS(RADIANS(90-[tblClosestCities].[Latitude])) + SIN(RADIANS(90-[tblnewbid].[Latitude])) * SIN(RADIANS(90-[tblClosestCities].[Latitude])) * COS(RADIANS([tblnewbid].[Longitude]-[tblClosestCities].[Longitude]))) AS " & Distance & ")"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM tblClosestCities, " & tblnewbid & " )"
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & Distance & " = MIN(" & Distance & ")"

    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError


rs1.Close

Set rs1 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

DoCmd.Hourglass False
MsgBox "The proxity of the city within the states have been added!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update table if SQL contains aggregate functions. Create temporary table first with minimum distances and then run update.